# I co-signed but found out i'm actually the primary account holder

Tags: auto-loan, co-sign

I co-signed my boyfriends auto loan so he could trade in his car and opt for lower car payments. I received a red light traffic ticket in the mail with my name on it, which i thought was odd. So I contacted the financial company (Ally) and turns out I am the primary account holder. 
After looking into it some more turns out the car dealership ran several inquires to get approved without notifying me that they were going to do so. Is there anything I can do legally to get my name off the loan or sell the car back to the dealership. Everything was done over the phone, so I never signed any legal documents. 
Thank you!

Comment: "Everything was done over the phone, so I never signed any legal documents."  Did the bank say that it was a recorded line and that you agreeing to it over the phone was legal authorization?

Answer (score 2):

Primary or secondary is a distinction without a difference.  You both "co-signed."  You both signed the loan, you both owe the money.  You both agreed to the terms of the contract.

Paying off the loan would remove your name from the loan.  Perhaps your boyfriend can go get a different loan to refinance the car.

Comment: But why did **she** get the ticket?

Comment: Because her name is on the title.  She can't possibly think that the camera would be able to distinguish between her and her boyfriend.

Comment: And is **his** name **also** on the title?

Comment: Could be, could not be.  It doesn't matter, the issue is the loan.  But obviously her name is on the title if the stupid, and depending on jurisdiction unenforceable, ticket was sent to her.